# Book recommendations about the solutions of quartic multivariable polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Let $P(x,y)$ denote a fourth-degree multivariable polynomial given by

$P(x,y)=\displaystyle\sum^{4}_{k+m=0}c_{k\,m}x^{k}y^{m}$,
in which $c_{km}$ are real constants.

Based on your wide experience, what are the best books that discuss the solutions, particular cases, and the usual methods to find the solutions of $P(x,y)$?

Comment: If you really mean $k+m=4$, then this is homogeneous, so the solution set is invariant under scaling and you're reduced to calculating the solutions of $P(x,1)$ and $P(1,y)$, which are polynomials in one variable of degree at most 4. From there you can use lots of fun techniques.

Comment: @KReiser. I hope you are doing well. Actually, I meant $\sum^{4}_{k+m=0}c_{km}x^{k}y^{m}$. I shall edit my question to properly state what I am actually searching for. Thank you so much for your comment.